# How do i attach the text to the left in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to use google scripts, all of the text is attached to the right and I cannot work like that.  How do I fix that and attach the text to the left?

I was trying the usual alt+shift that works in regular text fields but no help there.

Comment: Very unclear. Show the code or better explain what you mean.

Comment: @Mogsdad, I think OP means script editor or google sheets is setup is setup with Right to left text.

Comment: @Munkey - I think you mis-directed your comment, you probably meant Zig.

Answer (score 0):

IF your issue is that your sheet is setup right to left,
then please see the following link to fix.

[Right-To-Left text editing in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65166?hl=en)

I would paste in the information, but there are images for the icons that won't display.

Alternatively, In google sheets, click help, Sheets Help.
Then search for "Right to left text editing"

You will find the same info.

Essentially you need to go to menu, then settings, Check the box next to “Show right-to-left controls in the editor.” The setting is now applied across Docs, Sheets, and Slides.

You then have to refresh the sheet and look for the icon to change text orientation